# JsHint Error in Gruntfile

Tags: jshint, gruntfile

I get the following error after having updated VS2017: "Warning: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type object. Use --force to continue."
The jshint section of my Gruntfile:

```
jshint: {
            files: ['temp/*.js',
                'Scripts/common.js',
                'Scripts/renderImage.js',
                'Scripts/classifEditPreamble.js',
                'Scripts/displayPreamble.js',
                'Scripts/editionFilter.js',
                'Scripts/newRegistration.js',
                'Scripts/adminPanel.js'],
            options: {
                '-W069': false,
                'esnext': true
            }
        }
```

Comment: `require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt, {pattern: ['grunt-*', '@*/grunt-*', "!grunt-contrib-jshint"]});` try this. and please double check your file paths.

Answer (score 0):

Adding one line (reporterOutput) to options solved the problem. The error message is misleading!

```
options: {
            '-W069': false,
            'reporterOutput': "",
            'esnext': true
        }
```